# How to show a EditRef control in front of a specific workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which used to work pretty well in Excel 2010. I recently migrated to Excel 2013 and it started misbehaving. The code trys to open a workbook and, if the opening was succesful, it showd a useform with some RefEdit controls.

```
Sub SetAddressess()
    This program opens the first file path indicated by MacroFolderOffice2010 and ask for the user to select
    the cells with all the necessary information to data reduction

    Dim FirstSamplePath As Range
    Dim WorkbookOpened As Workbook 'Name of the workbook opened

    If SamList_Sh Is Nothing Then
        Call PublicVariables
    End If

    If Len(SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine).Value) <> 0 Or Len(SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine).End(xlDown).Value) <> 0 Then
        Set AllSamplesPath = SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine, SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine).End(xlDown))
    Else
        Call MacroFolderOffice2010
            Set AllSamplesPath = SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine, SamList_Sh.Range(SamList_FilePath & SamList_FirstLine).End(xlDown))
    End If

    Set FirstSamplePath = AllSamplesPath.Item(1)

    If Len(FirstSamplePath.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There is no samples in SamList sheet. SetAddressess procedure.", vbOKOnly
        End
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    ScreenUpd = Application.ScreenUpdating
        If ScreenUpd = False Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True

           Set WorkbookOpened = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FirstSamplePath)

            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox MissingFile1 & FirstSamplePath & MissingFile2 & " - " & "SetAddressess procedure"
                    Call UpdateFilesAddresses
                        Call UnloadAll
                            End
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Box4_Addresses.Show

        WorkbookOpened.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpd

End Sub
```

**After the code "Box4_Addresses.Show", the window blinks, the userform appears for a second, but neither the "WorkbookOpened" nor the "Box4_Address" stay visible. I have to switch the windows to see both of them.**

The Box4_Addresses is initialized using the code below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    If SampleName_UPb Is Nothing Then
        Call PublicVariables
    End If

    'Page Address controls
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawHg202 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit1_202
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb204 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit2_204
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb206 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit3_206
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb207 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit4_207
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb208 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit20_208
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawTh232 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit5_232
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawU238 = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit6_238
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawHg202Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit7_202Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb204Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit8_204Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb206Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit9_206Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb207Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit10_207Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawPb208Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit21_208Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawTh232Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit11_232Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawU238Header = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit12_238Header
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawCyclesTime = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit15_CyclesTime
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawAnalysisDate = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit22_AnalysisDate
    Set Box4_Addresses_RawNumCycles_Each_Sample = Box4_Addresses.RefEdit23_Num_Cycles

End Sub
```

The call for the "SampleName_UPb" is just to check if this public variable was set. I already checked if it was not set during the code execution, so I believe the problem is not related to the possible execution of the procedure "PublicVariables". Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are asking for a solution to. Is it that the form is not visible after opening?

Comment: Dear @ClintB, it is exactly what you said. The figure I posted may have created some confusion, sorry.

Comment: Firstly I would check the form properties. (Categories>>Behaviour>>showModel=TRUE). If that doesnt thelp them try this solution. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26766076/Can-we-keep-the-userform-always-on-top-vba.html 
Note: I'm not sure if we are meant to link to other sites

Comment: The problem appears to be in managing the ActiveWindow. When opening a workbook Windows will create a new window, activate that window and show the new workbook in it. Your code ensures that the screen is updated accordingly. However, when you open a userform it will show in the window of the document that called it which should be the one containing the code. It seems that this conflict isn't managed as it used to be. The solution should be in managing the ActiveWindow explicitly in your code.